# How to Disable material design Fragment Navigation Drawer inside a particular Activity

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, material-design

I used a Fragment Navigation Drawer and FloatingActionButton inside my application. Clicking on the FloatingActionButton takes me to the New Activity. Now I have added setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) and it takes me to the parent activity. But inside this activity I am still ableto swipe the Fragment Navigaion Drawer and when I click on the drawer items app crashes. I want to disablethe Fragment Navigation Drawer Inside the second activity. How would i do this. Here is my code.

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
    drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.icon_launcher);

    FloatingActionButton actionButton = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(this).setContentView(imageView).build();
    actionButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,AddTopicActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_body"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />`


</LinearLayout>


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:name="mobi.com.swachapp.FragmentDrawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

FragmentDrawer.java

```
public class FragmentDrawer extends Fragment {

private static String TAG = FragmentDrawer.class.getSimpleName();

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private NavigationDrawerAdapter adapter;
private View containerView;
private static String[] titles = null;
private FragmentDrawerListener drawerListener;

public FragmentDrawer() {

}

public void setDrawerListener(FragmentDrawerListener listener) {
    this.drawerListener = listener;
}

public static List<NavDrawerItem> getData() {
    List<NavDrawerItem> data = new ArrayList<>();

    int[] icons = {R.drawable.home_icon,R.drawable.usersignin,R.drawable.savedarticles,R.drawable.addtopic,R.drawable.trending,R.drawable.photography,R.drawable.photos,R.drawable.video,R.drawable.survey};
   // preparing navigation drawer items
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length && i < icons.length; i++) {
        NavDrawerItem navItem = new NavDrawerItem();
        navItem.setTitle(titles[i]);
        navItem.IconId = icons[i];
        data.add(navItem);
    }
    return data;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // drawer labels
    titles = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_labels);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflating view layout
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);

    adapter = new NavigationDrawerAdapter(getActivity(), getData());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            drawerListener.onDrawerItemSelected(view, position);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(containerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    }));

    return layout;
}


public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, final Toolbar toolbar) {
    containerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            toolbar.setAlpha(1 - slideOffset / 2);
        }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });

}

public static interface ClickListener {
    public void onClick(View view, int position);

    public void onLongClick(View view, int position);
}

static class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private ClickListener clickListener;

    public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    }
}

public interface FragmentDrawerListener {
    public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position);
}
}
```

AddTopicActivity.java

```
public class AddTopicFragment extends ActionBarActivity {

private Toolbar mToolbar;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ma);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

}

}
```

I want that when this activity starts Fragment Navigation Drawer functionalities will disabled completely. I am able to remove the Drawer icon but still when i swipe from left drawer comes into the picture.

Thanks.

Comment: But why you select navigation activity while project creating?

Comment: sorry i don't get what are you trying to say?

Comment: i see that you are using the same layout file **R.layout.activity_main** for both the activities.. any reason for doing that?

Comment: ok i got that, its the mistake. Thanks

Comment: No problem..Happy Coding!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Add inside `AddTopicActivity` second activity. it will lock to swipe

for lock

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

for unlock

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
```

Comment: I used the custom Drawer Layout using the Fragment, code shown in the FragmentDrawer,java class. and by adding these lines app crashes.

Comment: might be `mDrawerLayout` is `null` you have to make `static` to access in other activity

Comment: ya i made the mDrawerLayout static and now app doesn't crashes but still drawer is accessible

Comment: `FragmentDrawer.mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);`

Comment: i just created a new function in FragmentDrawer.java public void DisableDrawerLayout()
    {
        if(mDrawerLayout!= null) {
            Log.i("DrawerLayout","NotNull");
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
        }} and called it in the AddTopicActivity.java i am able to see that the function is called but the Navigation Drawer is still present

Comment: means you can still open with gesture in `AddTopicActivity` have you tried with `FragmentDrawer.mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CL‌​OSED);`. i think problem in `mDrawerLayout` object

Comment: ya i have tried this way also but i am still able to open the drawer with gesture. Can you plz help in solving this that where is the problem actually. thanks